# D3 Zooming and Pan not working for entire map, just the projection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps

Hopefully this is the right place for this. This is my first time working in d3 and I'm tracking some paths across latitudes (.bars) on a mercator projection map of the world.

While I'm nowhere near where I want to be with this map (trying to animate change over time, and then include tooltips to the .bars): I'm stuck with the zoom feature. I've gotten it to change the scale of the projection when zooming, but it has no effect on my rectangle shapes (.bars). Could someone take a look and let me know what's going on? Why are the rectangles not scaling on zoom? Am I not correctly accessing them in my zoom function?

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 550,
    scale0 = (width - 1) / 2 / Math.PI;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    // .append("g");

var g = svg.append("g");

var bars = svg.append("rect");

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .scale(scale0)
    .scaleExtent([scale0, 8 * scale0])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var color = d3.scale.quantize() // Takes data value inputs and will return colors
    .range(['rgb(215,48,39)','rgb(244,109,67)','rgb(253,174,97)','rgb(254,224,144)','rgb(255,255,191)','rgb(224,243,248)','rgb(171,217,233)','rgb(116,173,209)','rgb(69,117,180)']);

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale((width + 1) / 2 / Math.PI)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .precision(.1);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

svg
    .call(zoom)
    .call(zoom.event);

d3.json("world-110m.json", function(error, world) {
  if (error) throw error;

  g.insert("path", ".graticule")
    .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land))
    .attr("class", "land")
    .attr("d", path);

  g.insert("path", ".graticule")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
    .attr("class", "boundary")
    .attr("d", path);

  d3.csv("data/apr_dove.csv", function(data) {

    // Returns value based on min/max of data set to Colorbrewer colors
    color.domain([
      d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.average_revisit; }),
      d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.average_revisit; })
    ]);

    // Defining the rectangle's attributes by monthly data of satellites  (latitude and average revisit_rate)
    g.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("class", "bars")
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        // console.log(projection.translate([0, 0.5])[1])
        return projection([0, d.latitude - 0.5])[1] - projection([0, d.latitude])[1];
      })
      .attr("opacity", .6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        //Get data value
        var value = d.average_revisit;

        if (value) {
                //If value exists…
                return color(value);
        } else {
                //If value is undefined…
                return "#ccc";
        }
       })
       //Define position of each rectangle by it's latitude from the data
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + projection([-180, d.latitude]) + ")"
      })
      .attr("d", path);
  });
});

function zoomed() {
  projection
      .translate(zoom.translate())
      .scale(zoom.scale());

  svg.selectAll("*")
      .attr("d", path);
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/sadbumblebee/64581d15b89b361a17a85e8f37172673.js"></script>


<script src="https://gist.github.com/sadbumblebee/359fc826e4e55c8c3dcb3d279783e910.js"></script>
```

Comment: please also share your apr_dove.csv and world-110m.json via github gist.

Comment: Added the csv and json. Can't seem to get the embed to work in Stackoverflow though, I'm pretty new here.

Comment: So I might have a slight fix that I barely grasp, but @Cyril I've now put `g.selectAll(".bars")
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return projection([0, d.latitude - 0.5])[1] - projection([0, d.latitude])[1];
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + projection([-180, d.latitude]) + ")"
      })
      .attr("width", 15000);`

within my zoomed function at the end. I think it's updating the drawn heights and locations of the rectangles. The width part, is a bad hack because I can't figure out why it translate left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea to get the appropriate width would be to basis it on the size of your land path:

```
var land;
d3.json("world-110m.json", function(error, world) {
  if (error) throw error;

  land = g.insert("path", ".graticule")
    .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land))
    .attr("class", "land")
    .attr("d", path);

  ....

function getLandWidth() {
  return land ? land.node().getBBox().width : 0;
}

...

function zoomed() {

  projection
    .translate(zoom.translate())
    .scale(zoom.scale());

  svg.selectAll("path")
    .attr("d", path);

  g.selectAll(".bars")
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return projection([0, d.latitude - 0.5])[1] - projection([0, d.latitude])[1];
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + projection([-180, d.latitude]) + ")"
    })
    .attr("width", getLandWidth());

}
```

---

Full code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iNsbvJehg2GrhiBAJhGG?p=preview).

Comment: That worked for me! Thanks, I'll keep it in my code.

Since sharing this last night, realized that my svg selections were all over the place @Mark, hopefully now I'm more sorted out.

I'm moving on to tooltips and animating the rectangles to update with monthly data. Can't seem to get the tooltip to update the rectangle styles though. I'll likely post on it too 